# How do I call the method correctly?

Tags: java

So, I need to be able to call the `.addClients()` method, and run it as suppose to, however I can't seem to figure out how to get it to run. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you also have any comments on how to enhance my code, that would come in handy, thanks in advance!
PS. I can't make the method static, I have to figure out a way of calling it without the method being static.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class BankApp {
    private SavingsAccount[] clients;
    public BankApp() {
        Scanner bb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many clients do you want on the 
system?");
        int numofclients = bb.nextInt();
        this.clients = new SavingsAccount[numofclients];
        clients.addClients();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BankApp ba = new BankApp();
    } 
}
```

<------------------------------------------------->

```
import java.util.*;
public class SavingsAccount {
    private SavingsAccount[] clients;
    private double Balance;
    private String ID, Name;
    public SavingsAccount(String startingID, String startingName, double 
startingBalance) {
        this.Balance = startingBalance;
        this.ID = startingID;
        this.Name = startingName;
    }
    public void addClients() {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < clients.length) {
            System.out.println("What is ID of user " + (i + 1));
            this.clients[i]  = new SavingsAccount("DF01", "Dandy", 
10.00);
            i++;
        }
    }
    public double getBalance() {
        return Balance;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return ID;
    }
}
```

I expect the `addClients()` to populate the `clients[]`. However `addClients()` has to run first.

Comment: This code is broken. SavingAccount should not hold an array of SavingAccount objects, nor should it have any UI (user interaction) code. Instead it should represent the state of a single Saving account, that's it. A Bank class, or something similar, should have the array (or better an ArrayList). All UI code (println's getting user input) belongs elsewhere, here likely in the main method.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this part of your code:

```
this.clients = new SavingsAccount[numofclients];
clients.addClients();
```

Here, your `clients` variable points to an **array of SavingsAccounts**, and each `SavingsAccount` has its own `addClients()` method.

So, I believe what you want is to loop over the elements of the array?

```
for(SavingsAccount client : clients) {
    client.addClients();
}
```

But, as the above community wiki mentioned, this looks like a rather odd design. Why do you have an array of `SavingsAccount`'s as a field of the `SavingsAccount` class?

Comment: I am just answering the direct question, not re-designing the OP's entire application.

Comment: But it is neither helpful nor correct. Sorry, I have to call it as I see it. You should consider correcting or deleting.

Answer (score -1):

You are worried about the wrong thing I'm afraid. Your problem isn't how to call the `addClients(...)` but rather should be how to structure the program correctly from the ground up, since your current design is broken.

The SavingsAccount class should concern itself with the state (variables) and behaviors (methods) of a *single* savings account, nothing more and nothing less. It shouldn't hold an array of SavingsAccount, nor should it have any user interaction (UI) code within it such as println statements, unless they're temporary and for debugging purposes.

Instead the BankApp class should hold the instance array, and perhaps the `addClient(...)` method.

Another driver class should hold the main method, and perhaps control all user interactions (ui).

Re-study your requirements and then re-design from the ground up.
I'm also guessing that you may need a Client class? I can't say for sure

Comment: That's what my university wants me to do, they want me to create a SavingsAccount array that holds the ID Name and Balance of the clients.

Comment: @tatejuan: Please re-read my answer above as I did not suggest **not** creating the array, but rather that **it does not belong within the SavingsAccount class**. Again I fear that you are confused over your requirements, and may wish to post the entire requirements with your question.

Comment: the there is an array of SavingsAccount type named 'clients' as a private and nonstatic member variable. The array must only be declared at the object member variable-level. This is what it asks me to do

Comment: You're forgetting to mention **where** the array should go. That's the whole point of this discussion

Comment: @tatejuan: The whole point of my post above is that the `clients` array should not be held within the SavingsAccount class but rather within a Bank class. Please re-read your instructions and reply back. Also, look at the more specific answer that I've posted to your question, one that shows exactly what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ahh, ok, now I know the angle that you are coming from, thanks for the help, will be implementing this to my program!

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is to get the SavingsAccount array **out** of the SavingsAccount class as it simply doesn't belong there. Again the SavingsAccount should concern itself with a single account only:

```
public class SavingsAccount {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double balance;

    public SavingsAccount(String iD, String name, double balance) {
        this.id = iD;
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    // .... getters and setters here

    public void deposit(double funds) {
        balance += funds;
    }

    public double withdrawal(double funds) {
        // check if the balance is adequate before withdrawing
        // .....
    }
}
```

The BankApp or perhaps more simply Bank.java class should hold the array **and** the addClient method, and this method should accept a single SavingsAccount object. Again the method does not belong in SavingsAccount

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankApp {
    private SavingsAccount[] clients;
    private int accountIndex = 0;

    public BankApp(int clientCount) {
        clients = new SavingsAccount[clientCount];
    }

    // keep it simple -- it simply adds a client if there is room in the array
    public void addClient(SavingsAccount account) {
        if (accountIndex >= clients.length) {
            // you've got a problem -- throw an exception
        } else {
            clients[accountIndex] = account;
            accountIndex++;
        }
    }

    // methods to print a client, to print all clients, to remove a client,.....
```

Then inside the BankApp class (or elsewhere), have a main method that *drives* your program:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // User interface goes here
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many clients do you want on the system? ");
        int numofclients = scanner.nextInt();
        BankApp bank = new BankApp(numofclients);

        for (int i = 0; i < numofclients; i++) {
            // get id, name, balance of each client
            // create anew SavingsAccount object with this info
            // call bank.addClient(account); to add it to the bank
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}
```